# Is there a semantical difference between “what do you study” and “what are you studying”?

Tags: tense

> 1. What do you study at college?
> 2. What are you studying at college?

It seems to me that in 1 it can mean a generic YOU. Hence, 1 can mean "What does one study at college?"

In 2, it is more a specific you. I am asking my interlocutor what they are studying at college.

But on the other hand, they may mean the same with the meaning of the sentence 2.

That's what I think. Tell me what you think. What difference can there be between them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fundamental difference in meaning between these two phrases.

In both cases, 'you' can refer to EITHER a single individual or to a group.